# Adding Event to a Method

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I have a HTTP class that I've created, and I would to, if possible, attach a method each time either HTTP.post() or HTTP.get() is called. I'd like to be able to attach the event either before, or after.

I see this being done in a lot of Frameworks for the web, such as Wordpress and Symfony, but I'd like to do something similar on my WinForms app.

What design pattern am I looking for to achieve this so I can go and Google it.

Comment: Are you just looking to add an event via code?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743596.aspx

Comment: @JoeKorolewicz yes. I will check your link now.

Comment: @JoeKorolewicz I've checked the link. I'm aware of attaching methods this way. A button, as in the example, already has events handlers. What I want to do is build event handlers into my HTTP class so I can attach events before and/or after the HTTP requests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create events on your objects and invoke them from anywhere in your code. I do this quite often.

```
public event EventHandler Getting;
public event EventHandler Setting;

void get()
{
    if (Getting  != null)
        Getting.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}

void post()
{
    if (Setting  != null)
        Setting.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Then other classes can handle these events something like this:

```
myHttp.Getting += myHttp_Getting;

public void myHttp_Getting(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

**Edits:**

You could also invoke the event like this:

```
void post()
{
    if (Setting  != null)
        Setting(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

You can only invoke an event from within its own class. This is not a problem because being able to do otherwise would cause really confusing code. Always check if it is null, because if there are no subscribers it will be null and will through a `NullReferenceException` when you invoke it.

Comment: What is this design pattern called? Is it the Observer Listener pattern?

Comment: It's not a design pattern. It's a syntax. This code is demonstrating the event syntax.

Comment: The `Invoke` is also optional, i.e. you can do `Getting(this, EventArgs.Empty)` to have the same effect.

Comment: Personally, I call `Invoke` so that I can easily see that I am calling an event instead of calling a local method. But you are right, @luksan.

Comment: If you are looking for a pattern to call this, you might consider the Publish and Subscribe pattern. The event syntax uses this pattern but it is built into the language. Patterns are usually more abstract.

Comment: Yeah, it's actually the `event` keyword that makes it so you can only invoke the delegate from its own class. If you omit `event`, it behaves like an ordinary delegate and outside classes can invoke it as well.

Comment: Yeah, that's true too. I'd recommend the event keyword as it leads to better practices, but yeah, you can use this syntax with any delegate type.